# Can I integrate smart contracts in Django application

Tags: solidity, django

I'm new to Blockchain and being from a Microsoft technology stack, a little biased to develop my smart contracts using Solidity. I am using truffle and NodeJS ecosystem. Now I've a Django application interface which needs to be integrated with the smart contracts so need help on the directions moving forward.

I'm working on automating and migrating all transactions of a Logistics system on blockchain. The existing system is on Django - python so need suggestions and guidance on the tech stack, feasibility and limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, follow below steps:

1. Write a smart contract,
2. Deploy smart contract in Eth network
3. Use `web3.py` to integrate/call smart contract/eth method's

   - [Documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)
   - [SDK](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py)